# atd dead but subsys locked

Tags: services, at, pidfile

After I killed the `atd` process by hand (`sudo kill <PID>`), I can no longer start `at` jobs:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ echo ls | at 'now + 1 minute'
job 6 at 2016-05-09 20:17
Can't open /var/run/atd.pid to signal atd. No atd running?
```

Also, I see:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ service atd status
atd dead but subsys locked
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ service atd restart
Stopping atd:                                              [FAILED]
Starting atd:                                              [FAILED]
[vagrant@localhost ~]$
```

I could reboot, since this is a Vagrant box expressly for playing around with, but I'd rather learn the "right way" to fix this.

How do I get `atd` running again?

(I'm running CentOS 6.6.)

Answer (score 1):

Aha, I feel silly now:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo service atd restart
Stopping atd:                                              [FAILED]
Starting atd:                                              [  OK  ]
[vagrant@localhost ~]$
```